# сделать бэкап в определенную папку

Tags: postgresql, cron, резервное-копирование

делаю бэкап, скрипт такого содержания

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
pg_dump db_name |gzip > db_$DATE.gz
find /home/dima/backups -name "*.gz" -mtime 7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

в cron'e у меня `30 02 * * * sh /home/dima/backups/backup.sh`

бэкапы делаются, но сохраняются в папку `/home/dima`, а нужно чтобы сохранялись в  `/home/dima/backups`

сделал через `mv /home/dima/db_$DATE.gz /home/dima/backups`, но это тоже не сработало, видимо из-за `DATE`

Какие у меня еще варианты? может непосредственно в кроне написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в pg_dump указываете нужную вам директорию:

```
pg_dump db_name |gzip > /home/dima/backups/db_$DATE.gz
```